# specify response for fiddler core

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore

I use fiddler core to intercept the request and provide a response to it. I know its possible to use saz files to save the response. But the problem is that I need to be able to customize the response. While its a saz file I cant customize the response manually.

Is there a way to save response caught by fiddler to a text file in json like format, so that I could edit it and could serve it as response to any request using fiddler core? For now i see I can save response as a plain text. But how do I load this request to fiddler or parse it with fiddler core to populate all the response properties? Is there some format I could use, that will allow me to manually edit the response?

UPDATE
I see I can just open saz archive, make my edits to reponse and use it to specify the response. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Also there is a way to save response session as har file. Is it possible to save one single response as har/saz file? Currently I can only save session and it contain all requests and responses. Is there a way to limit saved data to 1 request and 1 response?

Comment: Your "update" introduces a new and unrelated question; it would be better to file a new question rather than trying to have a conversation here. You can save as few or as many sessions to a SAZ file as you like.

Answer (score 2):

You have a SAZ file, which contains the full content of a response. Your code may load the SAZ File into FiddlerCore using the `Utilities.ReadSessionArchive` method. You will then have an array of `Session` objects.

As FiddlerCore receives requests, you can evaluate whether or not you wish to reply to each request using a previously-loaded response or whether you want to instead let the request flow through to the server. To let the request flow through to the server, do nothing.

To return a previously-generated response, in FiddlerCore 2.4.6.4+ (not yet released), simply call `utilAssignResponse` on the new Session. For earlier versions of FiddlerCore without this new method, your `OnBeforeRequest` method should call a method that looks something like this:

```
public void utilAssignResponse(Session oS, HTTPResponseHeaders oRH, byte[] arrBody)
  oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
  oS.oResponse.headers = (HTTPResponseHeaders)oRH.Clone();
  oS.responseBodyBytes = arrBody ?? Utilities.emptyByteArray;
  oS.oFlags["x-Fiddler-Generated"] = "Generated by myCode";
}
```

Comment: Eric, the problem of saz file is that I cant edit it manually. I mean content is in zipped. Is there any way to load response that is in plain text mode or in some format that I can edit, say in notepad?

Comment: You can edit a SAZ file using Fiddler. Open it. Select any session, right-click and choose Unlock for Editing. Edit the Session. Right-click and untick Unlock for Editing. Save the SAZ file once you're done modifying it. (Alternatively, your code can edit the Sessions after loading them from the SAZ file).